# .htaccess url rewrite code in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter

My site url is:

```
http://www.thebestincanada.ca/index.php?site/searchOther/restaurant/Victoria
```

I want to rewrite the url as:

```
http://www.thebestincanada.ca/restaurant/Victoria
```

What would be the url rewrite rule for this?

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) default.php?title=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3
```

but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a "route" rule by modifying

> application/config/routes.php

instead of adding rules for .htaccess file.
This is CI reference topic:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

sample code:

```
route['restaurant/(.*)']='site/searchOther/restaurant/$1';
```

if you got other categories, just like this:

```
route['((restaurant|shop|park)/.*)']='site/searchOther/$2';
```